# Two html frames need to be linked on button click

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have two frames on a page: `map.html` and `chart.html`

`map.html` holds a Google map on which I can draw polygons and input entered by the user gets saved into the database. Backend is written in PHP.

`chart.html` displays the charts based on the input entered.

What I need is `charts.html` to dynamically change every time the user clicks on save button.

I tried refreshing after specified time interval, but that is grossly inefficient.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please visit the [help] to see how to ask a question so it does not get voted down and closed. If the frames content comes from the same origin, you can use parent.otherframename.someFunction() to access

Comment: Okay thank you. I shall try doing it. @mplungjan